# File name matching with -e and regular expressions in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to check for the existence of a file in a directory. The file name has a pattern like:

```
/d1/d2/d3/abcd_12345_67890.dat
```

In my program, I will know the file name up to `abcd_`

I need to write an `if` condition using `-e` option and find the files matching above given pattern.

Comment: You have a bit of an XY Problem here: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341. Explain to use what you need to accomplish rather than how you think you have to do it. Why do you need to write an if condition with -e? Do you just think you need to do that? How do you know what filename you want if you only know part of the filename? What answer to you need at the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to return a list of existing files whose name matches a pattern:

```
my @files = glob '/d1/d2/d3/abcd_*.dat';
```

In this case, there is no need to perform the `-e` filetest.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `-e` for partial file name matches.

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Slurp;

my ($name, $path) = basename('/d1/d2/d3/abcd_');
my $exists = grep { /^\Q$name\E_[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{5}\.dat\z/ } read_dir $path;
```

If the directory contains a lot of files, you can still keep your program's footprint constant by using [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and using [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) in a while loop.

I used `File::Slurp::read_dir` here to present an uncluttered solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if the file exists and the filename has a particular format. If this is what you want you can do this:

```
use File::Basename;

$file = "/d1/d2/d3/abcd_12345_67890.dat";

print "SUCCESS" if(-e $file and (basename($file)=~m{^abcd_}))
```

Comment: Venkat doesn't know the entire filename, just the first 5 characters, according to the question as it stands now (edited by you?).  This doesn't seem to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foreach $f (</d1/d2/d3/*.dat>) {if ($f =~ /\w{4}_\d{5}_\d{5}\.dat/)  {print $f}};
```

Comment: Angle brackets with an * is just syntactic sugar for glob. The explicit approach is cleaner.