# How to use regex on file test operator

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File name matching with -e and regular expressions in perl.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222410/file-name-matching-with-e-and-regular-expressions-in-perl)

for ex

if (-e /home/tree/a*) { 
  print "file found"
}

How to use regex on file test operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a regex on the [file existence test operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

If you want to check a filename for existence using a regex, you will have to retrieve a file list, using *e.g.* [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) or [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (note that glob has lightweight syntax as `</home/tree/*>`), and then filter it using regexes.

Note that in your case, that "expression" you use, `/home/tree/a*`, could be interpreted as a glob pattern instead of a regex.  If that's what you intended, you could use a glob directly, as in:

```
if ( () = </home/tree/a*> ) { print "file found" }
```

See comments for a discussion of why/how not to use `glob` as a test condition.

Comment: Do *not* use glob in scalar context like this.  If you put that in a loop and there's a single a* file, you will see that half the time it fails.  You can do `if ( () = </home/tree/a*> )`

Comment: This isn't a good solution, since the glob retains state when invoked in scalar context.  If there are three files in /home/tree that start with "a", then the fourth time this if statement is encountered, the boolean test will evaluate to false.

Comment: I didn't intend this answer to become a `glob` guide (and we're probably missing the OP's big picture), but we might as well have it demonstrated correctly indeed.  Editing.

Answer (score 1):

How come no one likes readdir()?  I stopped using glob the first time I ran into the state issue mentioned in Sean's comment to JB's answer.

This will give you an idea of how to use readdir:

```
opendir(DIR, "/home/tree") or die $!;
my @matches = grep(/^a.*/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);
print join("\n", @matches);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with readdir except that it's less terse.  Useless use of `.*` there; `/^a/` matches everything `/^a.*/` does.

Comment: OK, so me regular expressions tend to be a bit primitive.  But the post is really about the readdir!  :-)  I vastly prefer readir over glob because you get the same results everytime (assuming the dir contents aren't changing!), whereas glob "consumes" the filenames and you can never get them back.